# How could I reliably estimate the maximum current that a photodiode can handle without looking at the datasheet?

Tags: current, photodiode, maximum-ratings

I'm looking for a way to determine the maximum current that a photodiode could handle without having to look at a datasheet. I'd like the method to be as similar as possible to how I would test for an unknown LED:

For an LED I would connect it to a variable power supply, slowly increase the voltage until I got an acceptable glow, then measure the current flow at that voltage. Not perfect, but as long as I'm happy with the light intensity and slight risk to LED health, it works well enough.

The problem is that a photodiode doesn't have a visual indicator of light like an LED has.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you planning to use the photodiode forward biased, reverse biased, or zero-biased?

Comment: I was thinking more in general terms. But if I had to choose, I'd say forward bias.

Comment: @rrowhe4d Why are you considering forcing a maximum current through a photodiode?

Comment: Given the photodiode's typical uses, I too wonder which field of application would require to determine its maximum forward current. There's no analogy in LED uses, of course.

Comment: (1) Read the data sheet. (2) Use a LED instead - they're actually rated for many milliamps of forward current, yet they still provide light->current in reverse bias or zero bias.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Expose the photodiode to the brightest light that you can. Bright sunlight, perhaps. Then measure the current.

In the circuit below measure the voltage across the resistor and use Ohm's law.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgJnfjm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Most semiconductor device limits are from heating. As long as the junction temperature doesn't exceed ~ 125 °C, there likely won't be any problem.

It is doubtful (perhaps unless you shine a laser at it), that a photodiode can generate enough current to self-damage.